# How to do Ruby's instance_eval in Java?

Tags: java

Here's the total `instance_eval` experience, in Ruby:

```
def function(&block)
    "object".instance_eval(&block)
end

function{ p(length) }
```

Note that, inside `function{}`, the method `length` bonded with the string `"object"`. I didn't need to write a dot or anything before the `length` to get the evaluated string's context.

(The output is `6`, by the way...)

Now, how to do that to a `Runnable` in Java? Java 6 for Android preferred. The bonded object doesn't need to be a string, just so long as it is bonded. Also note that I am not talking about `instance_eval`'s other function, evaluating strings as source, because I am aware that Java is compiled and not interpreted like Ruby. I just need the syntactic sugar.

---

The goal is, using JATL's HTML module (which builds HTML), to replace this:

```
html.a();
html.href("www.duckduckgo.com");
html.raw("Not El Goog");
html.end();
```

...with this:

```
html.a(() -> {
    href("www.duckduckgo.com");
    raw("Not El Goog");
});
```

Notice the redundant `html.end();` line went away. This replaces procedure with structure, so that the structure of the Builder Pattern matches the structure of the output HTML.

(Also, JATL HTML comes with the ability to pass a block to HTML's constructor; we also don't need that because we DO need the top level of the Builder pattern to use procedural code...)

Comment: In general, you should take the time to learn a language's idioms, rather than just trying to translate from one to the other. Java doesn't have a lot of syntactic sugar at all. Perhaps look at Kotlin though? Also why Java _6_?

Comment: another point of the question is to provide a chrestomathy in the search engines. "How to do X from Language Y in Language Z." There wasn't one for this question. I'm using whatever Java it is that Android currently uses, so plz don't give me some Java 17 idiom tx. If you can admit Java can't do it that's okay too.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could think of achieving this is using reflection. This is a method where in you can pass any method name with it's parameters(if any) and it will be called on `String` class

```
void function(String functionName) {
    try {
        objectInstance.getClass().getMethod(functionName).invoke(objectInstance);
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        System.err.println("Not such method exist" + functionName);
    }
}
```

Let's say you want to call `length` or `isEmpty` method, you can invoke using

```
function("length") or function("isEmpty")
```

You can deep dive into `getMethod` and `invoke` to make the method more generic. That is, if the method that you want to call take argument, you can pass parameter to the `invoke` method and pass the class type in `method`. Similarly for other constraints you want to incorporate. Read about [Java Reflection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/index.html) here

Comment: thanks for the example of reflection, yet I need a block. I want to clean up a ton of code that uses the Builder Pattern; see the addenda